# Using external javascript script in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a javascript file, myScript.js, with the following content:

```
function run(file) {
    // some operations
}
```

How can I use the '*run*' function inside a TypeScript file?

I've read similar questions but didn't find their answers clear enough: where I declare the function? how do I reference the declaration file etc..

Comment: You need to [write a declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html) for that script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a 3rd party js file with TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160028/using-a-3rd-party-js-file-with-typescript)

Comment: I think that the other answers are not details enough. Where should I declare it? where is the reference to the js file? That's the information I'm looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript does not know about the `run` function. You'll have to declare it:

```
declare function run(file: any): any;
```

Now this works:

```
run(myFile);
```

EDIT: you can also look into using "--allowJs" tsc parameter [mentioned here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.8.html), but I have no experience with it.

EDIT 2: If the external script is a published library, chances are that there is a *typings* file (.d.ts) for it. Check out the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) tool in that case.

Comment: Where should I declare it? where is the reference to the js file?

Comment: You put it in a `.d.ts` file (`myfile.d.ts`) and you reference it: `/// <reference path="myfile.d.ts" />`

Comment: @NitzanTomer thanks, now I can compile but I'm getting runtime error 'run is not defined'.

Comment: That probably means that you're not really including that actual js file and so `run` isn't defined

Comment: You can declare it in same file (using 'declare' keyword). But you have to provide the script at runtime (e.g using a script tag)