# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null | undefined'

Tags: typescript

I'm adding some TS features to an existing React JS project. One of the existing JS functions has default params of null

```
  const existingFunction = ({ firstName = null, lastName = null }) => {}
```

If I try to use that function and provide `string`s for those parameters, I get the following error

```
existingFunction({ firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" });

Error:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null | undefined'.
```

I've tried typing the params but I keep getting the same error.

```
type Name = {
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
}
const user:Name = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" }
existingFunction(user)

Error:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null | undefined'.
```

The only way I can get this working is to type the `firstName` and `lastName` properties as `any` types, which I'd prefer not to do

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**EDIT**:
`existingFunction` is a JavaScript function so I can't add types to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing function needs better typing.  The right call signature is like

```
declare const existingFunction: (
  param: { firstName?: string | null, lastName?: string | null }
) => void
```

Since that function is in JavaScript, you would need to do something like [use JSDoc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html#providing-type-hints-in-js-via-jsdoc) to provide type hints.  Maybe:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Param 
 * @property {string | null} [firstName]
 * @property {string | null} [lastName]
 * @param {Param} p 
 */
const existingFunction = (
    { firstName = null, lastName = null }
) => { };

existingFunction({ firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" }); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKgBAUAJgpgxgGwIYCcZjgewHYGcAuYMAHgJYGnYDmAYgK7Zz6k4BcYAFBGGAA6pIAtuwDeYAGakUBAHJCYAfnYEUlKmAA+YbHQQIANGGSz5SsCrWbtuhGAC+EAJRgAvAD4wAN0ykoEEMAQEKAg3OAAAvgAnrwwsOJgIgDyAEYAVvD4dmAACgKCkGARvCiYsSjRiRbUVjp62QDaktL4coIwALphYOElZTAVUVX4qjVadQiNxq3yXUU9-ChCiXlLgtm8hQEQWHiEJOTM1PSMzDiunNw8iRJSJu0XE4bTbegu1nr2Tq4eYnYA3EEDhRjgwmCxsBwxM17jB2AAiABSmAAFth4c8kLCEQBlQSkfAo+H2Rz-IA)

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
const existingFunction = ({ firstName = null, lastName = null }:
  {firstName?: string | null, lastName?: string | null}) => {}
```

Comment: `existingFunction` is a JavaScript function though. Sorry maybe that wasn't clear (I can edit my post)

Comment: Oh, I see, so you need something more like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181938/using-external-javascript-script-in-typescript