# Access function defines in JavaScript file from TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a function X within a JavaScript file “MyFile.js” in the following path of an Angular 4 project : /assets/js/MyFile.js

I already added the path in the angular-cli.json into the scripts section.

```
...
“scripts”:
[ “assets/js/MyFile.js”]
...
```

**Question:** How can access the function X  in MyFile.js from a typescript component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a 3rd party js file with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160028/using-a-3rd-party-js-file-with-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can call a function from a script added via `.angular-cli.json`, although you can implement IIFEs that way. Normal usage is for external libraries (bootstrap.js, collapse, animations and the like) as they get added as `<script>` tags in the `index.html`.

Rather than adding it to your angular-cli.json, it's easier to import it in your components

1. Give MyFile a .ts extension to avoid having to pass the --allowJs flag. E.g., MyFile.ts
2. Make sure to export your functions. If you have several, you might put them in a class and make them static (but that's a different question). Here's what I did:

_

```
// myfile.ts
export const myFunction = () => {
  console.log('hello');
};
```

_

3. Import the script into the desired component via `import { myFunction } from '../assets/js/myFunction'`

_

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { myFunction} from '../assets/js/myfile';

@Component({  
  selector: 'app-root',  
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']  
})  


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
    myFunction();
  }
}
```

_